# Unity Inspector Text Label at Position

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to spruce up my Inspector but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to draw text at a specified position in the inspector. I have drawn a colored rectangle on the sample inspector below and want to draw text (like a label) on top of it.

[image]

**How can I draw text/label at the "X" position shown above?** I'm not really sure where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Implementing the answer:**

[image]

```
public override void OnGUI(Rect position)
{
    GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle();

    myStyle.fontSize = 16;
    myStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
    myStyle.padding.top = 5;
    myStyle.padding.left = -3;
    myStyle.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;

    Color32 color = colorSpacer.drawColor; // Custom Property Attribute
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(new Rect(position.x-11, position.y, position.width+11, position.height-2), color);
    Rect r = GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect();
    EditorGUI.LabelField(r, "Section Header", myStyle);
}
```

Comment: Please show your actual code of the custom inspector, so I can point you where to add the code for inserting the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are drawing your Custom Editor with [EditorGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.html), you can use the methods `LabelField`, `PrefixLabel`, `SelectableLabel` or `HandlePrefixLabel`, depending on your specific desired behavior.

If you are drawing with [EditorGUILayout](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.html), there are equivalents of those methods.

Also, the [HeaderAtribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HeaderAttribute.html) decorator does that without need for a custom Editor.

Comment: **EditorGUI.LabelField** was exactly what I needed.